# JointJS Adding a Port to a custom element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jointjs

I created a custom element using the [jointjs tutorial](https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/custom-elements) like this:

```
CustomRect = joint.dia.Element.define('example.CustomRect', {
  attrs: {
    rect: {
      refX: 0,
      refY: 0,
      refWidth: '116',
      refHeight: '70',
      strokeWidth: 1,
      stroke: '#000000',
      fill: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    label: {
      textAnchor: 'left',
      refX: 10,
      fill: 'black',
      fontSize: 18,
      text: 'text'
    },
    upperRect: {
      strokeWidth: 1,
      stroke: '#000000',
      fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.3)',
      cursor: 'pointer'
    }
  }
}, {
    markup: [{
      tagName: 'rect',
      selector: 'rect'
    },
    {
      tagName: 'text',
      selector: 'label'
    },
    {
      tagName: 'rect',
      selector: 'upperRect'
    }]
})

...

let customRect = new this.CustomRect()

customRect.attr({
  upperRect: {
    refWidth: '116',
    refHeight: '10',
    refX: 0,
    refY: -11,
    event: 'element:upperRect:pointerdown'
  }
})
```

Furthermore, I tried adding Ports with the [Port API for joint.dia.Element](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.3/joint.html#dia.Element.ports) like this:

```
customRect.addPorts([
  {
    args: {
      y: 30
    },
    z: 0
  }
]);
```

This does add Ports to my element, but they don't have the functionality they should have, so they're just some circles that do nothing.

The method shown in the [Port Tutorial](https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/ports) does not work, since I'm not using joint.shapes.devs.Model for my custom element, because then I can't customize it like the joint.dia.Element element (or at least I think I can't).

So, how can I add Ports to a custom element defined with joint.dia.Element that have the functionality they should have (as shown in the [Port Tutorial](https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/ports))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the documentation does not explain this clear enough. If you want to make the ports interactive you need to set the [magnet](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.3/joint.html#dia.attributes.magnet) attribute on them.

```js
const CustomRect = joint.dia.Element.define('example.CustomRect', {
  /* ... */
  attrs: {
    root: {
      // Don't allow the root of the element to be target of a connection
      magnet: false
    }
  },
  ports: {
    items: [{
      id: 'port1',
      attrs: {
        portBody: {
          // The port can be a target of a connection
          // The user can create a link from the port by dragging the port
          magnet: true
        }
      }
    }, {
      id: 'port2',
      attrs: {
        portBody: {
          // The port can only become a target of a connection
          // The logic can be modified via paper.options.validateMagnet()
          magnet: 'passive'
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}, {
  /* ... */
  portMarkup: [{
    tagName: 'circle',
    selector: 'portBody',
    attributes: {
      'r': 10,
      'fill': '#FFFFFF',
      'stroke': '#000000'
      // If all the magnets are `true` / `passive` feel free to define
      // the magnet here in the default port markup or per a port group
      // 'magnet': true
    }
  }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I needed to use '.joint-port-body' instead of portBody.